# Jasmine not using spyObject when angular service is injected at component level

Tags: angular, jasmine

**The background**

Hi I have tried to test a component that I created but the mock service that was provided was never used by Jasmine, only the real service was called. It turns out the root cause of the problem was my service is being provided at component level.

In my test, I mock the `QueryThreadService`

> queryThreadServiceSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('QueryThreadService', ['getQueryThread']);

then trigger `ngOnInit` by calling `fixture.detectChanges();` at this point I was expecting the mocked object to be used, but it did not, it called the real object.

After some research I realised that this could be to do with where I had provided the service, which - as you can see from the code below - is at component level. I change the service to be provided at module level and my tests worked.

**The question(s)**

Why do my tests not use the spy when I provide the service at component level and how should I write a test that provides a service at component level.

Is providing the service in the component a bad practice? I don't see it being referred to many places but it seems the right thing to do if you have service and component with a 1:1 ratio.

**The Component**

```
@Component({   
    selector: 'app-query-thread',   
    templateUrl: './query-thread.component.html',   
    styleUrls: ['./query-thread.component.scss'],   
    providers: [ QueryThreadService ] 
}) 
export class QueryThreadComponent implements OnInit {   

  @Input() query: QueriesData;

  queryThread: QueryResponse[];

  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _queryThreadService: QueryThreadService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._queryThreadService
      .getQueryThread(this._route.snapshot.params.accNumber, this.query.queryId.toString())
      .pipe(
        take(1)
      ).subscribe((data: QueryResponse[]) => this.updateQueryThread(data));   
  }

  private updateQueryThread(queries: QueryResponse[]): void {
    this.queryThread = queries;   
  } 
}
```

**The test**

```
...imports...
   
describe('QueryThreadComponent', () => {
    let queryThreadServiceSpyObj: jasmine.SpyObj<QueryThreadService>;

    let component: QueryThreadComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<QueryThreadComponent>;

    const organisationName = 'testOrg';

    beforeEach(() => {   
        queryThreadServiceSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('QueryThreadService', ['getQueryThread']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { snapshot: { params: { accNumber: 1 } } } },
                { provide: QueryThreadService, useValue: queryThreadServiceSpyObj },
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    
        queryThreadServiceSpyObj = TestBed.inject(QueryThreadService) as jasmine.SpyObj<QueryThreadService>;

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(QueryThreadComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        component.query = { queryId: 1, entityAssignedTo: organisationName } as QueriesData;
    });

    it('should populate the queryThread', fakeAsync(() => {
            queryThreadServiceSpyObj.getQueryThread.and.returnValue(of([
                {
                    queryItemId: 1,
                    queryHeaderId: 1,
                    entityName: 'test',
                    queryText: 'testText',
                    queryDate: '01012000',
                    status: QueryStatusEnum.NewQuery,
                    attachments: [
                        { attachmentId: 1, fileName: 'testFile' },
                        { attachmentId: 2, fileName: 'testFile2' }
                    ]
                }
            ] as QueryResponse[]));

            fixture.detectChanges();

            expect(component.query).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do something like [this](https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy/issues/91#issuecomment-626470446).

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   // have to add QueryThreadComponent to declarations (you seem to be missing it)
   declarations: [QueryThreadComponent],
   providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { snapshot: { params: { accNumber: 1 } } } },
})
.overrideComponent(QueryThreadComponent, 
   { set: { providers: [{ provide: QueryThreadService, useValue: queryThreadServiceSpyObj }] }})
.compileComponents();
```

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful, I will give it a try.